# Realm error "transformClassesWithRealmTransformerForDebug" failed to resolve types

Tags: android, android-studio, realm, android-studio-2.0

I'm using Realm on my android app, but I've got a strange error that is:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithRealmTransformerForDebug'.
>   javassist.CannotCompileException: setValues (Ljava/lang/String;)V in it.finproductions.discogsmanager.Structures.Collection: failed to resolve types

My Collection class is this:

```
public class Collection extends RealmObject {

private int Discogsid;
private int Folder;
//    String json;
private boolean Checked = false;
private String Artist;
private String Title;
private int Year;
private int Instanceid;
private String Format;
private String Cat;
private String Thumb;
//    DateTime dateadded;
private long Timestamp;

private String Tostringsearch;

private RealmList<Artists> Artists = new RealmList<>();
private RealmList<Formats> Formats = new RealmList<>();
private RealmList<Labels> Labels = new RealmList<>();

private boolean Values = false;
private boolean ToStringSearch = false;

public Collection() {
}

public Collection(int discogsid, int folder, String json) {
    this.Discogsid = discogsid;
    this.Folder = folder;
//        this.json = json;
    setValues(json);
}

public void setValues(String json) {
    JSONObject row;

    try {
        row = new JSONObject(json);
        try {
            ArrayList<String> artisti = new ArrayList<>();
            for (ArtistTrack a : Utils.getArtistsFromTrack(row.getJSONObject("basic_information")))
                artisti.add(a.getName());
            Artist = TextUtils.join(", ", artisti);

            JSONArray elencoArtisti = row.getJSONObject("basic_information").getJSONArray("artists");
            for (int i = 0; i < elencoArtisti.length(); i++) {
                Artists.add(new Artists(
                        Utils.takeJsonString(elencoArtisti.getJSONObject(i), "join"),
                        Utils.takeJsonString(elencoArtisti.getJSONObject(i), "name"),
                        Utils.takeJsonString(elencoArtisti.getJSONObject(i), "anv"),
                        Utils.takeJsonString(elencoArtisti.getJSONObject(i), "tracks"),
                        Utils.takeJsonString(elencoArtisti.getJSONObject(i), "role"),
                        Utils.takeJsonString(elencoArtisti.getJSONObject(i), "resource_url"),
                        Utils.takeJsonInt(elencoArtisti.getJSONObject(i), "join")
                ));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Artist = "";
        }

        try {
            Title = row.getJSONObject("basic_information").getString("title");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Title = "";
        }

        try {
            Year = row.getJSONObject("basic_information").getInt("year");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Year = 0;
        }

        try {
            Instanceid = row.getInt("instance_id");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Instanceid = 0;
        }

        try {
            Format = TextUtils.join(Utils.DIVISORFORLISTINDB, Utils.iterateEveryValueInArrayListForFormat(row.getJSONObject("basic_information"), "formats"));

            JSONArray elencoFormats = row.getJSONObject("basic_information").getJSONArray("formats");
            for (int i = 0; i < elencoFormats.length(); i++) {
                RealmList<Descriptions> descrizione = new RealmList<>();
                for (int ii = 0; ii < elencoFormats.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("descriptions").length(); ii++) {
                    descrizione.add(new Descriptions(elencoFormats.getJSONObject(i).getJSONArray("descriptions").getString(ii)));
                }

                Formats.add(new Formats(
                        Utils.takeJsonString(elencoFormats.getJSONObject(i), "name"),
                        Utils.takeJsonString(elencoFormats.getJSONObject(i), "qty"),
                        descrizione
                ));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Format = "";
        }

        try {
            Cat = TextUtils.join(Utils.DIVISORFORLISTINDB, Utils.iterateEveryValueInArrayListForLabel(row.getJSONObject("basic_information"), "labels"));

            JSONArray elencoLabels = row.getJSONObject("basic_information").getJSONArray("artists");
            for (int i = 0; i < elencoLabels.length(); i++) {
                Labels.add(new Labels(
                        Utils.takeJsonString(elencoLabels.getJSONObject(i), "name"),
                        Utils.takeJsonString(elencoLabels.getJSONObject(i), "entity_type"),
                        Utils.takeJsonString(elencoLabels.getJSONObject(i), "catno"),
                        Utils.takeJsonString(elencoLabels.getJSONObject(i), "resource_url"),
                        Utils.takeJsonInt(elencoLabels.getJSONObject(i), "id"),
                        Utils.takeJsonString(elencoLabels.getJSONObject(i), "entity_type_name")
                ));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("NO CAT");
            Cat = "";
        }

        try {
            Thumb = row.getJSONObject("basic_information").getString("thumb");
            if (Thumb.equals("")) {
                Thumb = Utils.DEFAULT_RELEASE;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Thumb = Utils.DEFAULT_RELEASE;
        }

        try {
            DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD");
            Timestamp = new Timestamp(formatter.parseDateTime(row.getString("date_added")).getMillis()).getTime();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        Tostringsearch = getArtist() + " " + getTitle() + " " + TextUtils.join(" ", getFormat()) + " " + TextUtils.join(" ", getCat()) + " " + getYear();
        Tostringsearch = Tostringsearch.toLowerCase();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }    }

public boolean isToStringSearch() {
    return ToStringSearch;
}

public void setToStringSearch(boolean toStringSearch) {
    ToStringSearch = toStringSearch;
}

public int getDiscogsid() {
    return Discogsid;
}

public void setDiscogsid(int discogsid) {
    Discogsid = discogsid;
}

public int getFolder() {
    return Folder;
}

public void setFolder(int folder) {
    Folder = folder;
}

public String getArtist() {
    return Artist;
}

public void setArtist(String artist) {
    Artist = artist;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return Title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    Title = title;
}

public int getYear() {
    return Year;
}

public void setYear(int year) {
    Year = year;
}

public int getInstanceid() {
    return Instanceid;
}

public void setInstanceid(int instanceid) {
    Instanceid = instanceid;
}

public void setFormat(String format) {
    Format = format;
}

public void setCat(String cat) {
    Cat = cat;
}

public String getThumb() {
    return Thumb;
}

public void setThumb(String thumb) {
    Thumb = thumb;
}

public void setTimestamp(long timestamp) {
    Timestamp = timestamp;
}

public String getTostringsearch() {
    return Tostringsearch;
}

public void setTostringsearch(String tostringsearch) {
    Tostringsearch = tostringsearch;
}

public RealmList<it.finproductions.discogsmanager.Structures.Artists> getArtists() {
    return Artists;
}

public void setArtists(RealmList<it.finproductions.discogsmanager.Structures.Artists> artists) {
    Artists = artists;
}

public RealmList<it.finproductions.discogsmanager.Structures.Formats> getFormats() {
    return Formats;
}

public void setFormats(RealmList<it.finproductions.discogsmanager.Structures.Formats> formats) {
    Formats = formats;
}

public RealmList<it.finproductions.discogsmanager.Structures.Labels> getLabels() {
    return Labels;
}

public void setLabels(RealmList<it.finproductions.discogsmanager.Structures.Labels> labels) {
    Labels = labels;
}

public boolean isValues() {
    return Values;
}

public void setValues(boolean values) {
    Values = values;
}

public List<String> getFormat() {
//        return format;
    return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Format.split(Utils.DIVISORFORLISTINDB)));
}

public List<String> getCat() {
//        return cat;
    return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Cat.split(Utils.DIVISORFORLISTINDB)));
}

public Date getTimestamp() {
    return new Date(Timestamp);
}

//    public String toStringExpectJson() {
//        return "TSEJ: " + Discogsid + ", " + Folder + ", " + getArtist() + ", " + getTitle() + ", " + getYear() + getInstanceid();
//    }

public String getToStringSearch() {
    return getArtist() + " " + getTitle() + " " + getFormat() + " " + getCat() + " " + getYear();
}

public void setChecked(boolean set) {
    Checked = set;
}

public boolean getChecked() {
    return Checked;
}

}
```

Artists, Formats and Labels are other classes that extends RealmObject.

I've tried to rebuid project, but nothing changes...

My Project build is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0-alpha5'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:0.88.3"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and my app app gradle starts with

```
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'
```

Someone can figure out what's the problem?

Edit 1:
Added entire setValues() method.

Edit 2:
Other called methods are:

```
public class Artists extends RealmObject {

    private String join;
    private String name;
    private String anv;
    private String tracks;
    private String role;
    private String resource_url;
    private int id;

    public Artists() {
    }

    public Artists(String join, String name, String anv, String tracks, String role, String resource_url, int id) {
        this.join = join;
        this.name = name;
        this.anv = anv;
        this.tracks = tracks;
        this.role = role;
        this.resource_url = resource_url;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getJoin() {
        return join;
    }

    public void setJoin(String join) {
        this.join = join;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAnv() {
        return anv;
    }

    public void setAnv(String anv) {
        this.anv = anv;
    }

    public String getTracks() {
        return tracks;
    }

    public void setTracks(String tracks) {
        this.tracks = tracks;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getResource_url() {
        return resource_url;
    }

    public void setResource_url(String resource_url) {
        this.resource_url = resource_url;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}


public class Artists extends RealmObject {

    private String join;
    private String name;
    private String anv;
    private String tracks;
    private String role;
    private String resource_url;
    private int id;

    public Artists() {
    }

    public Artists(String join, String name, String anv, String tracks, String role, String resource_url, int id) {
        this.join = join;
        this.name = name;
        this.anv = anv;
        this.tracks = tracks;
        this.role = role;
        this.resource_url = resource_url;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getJoin() {
        return join;
    }

    public void setJoin(String join) {
        this.join = join;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAnv() {
        return anv;
    }

    public void setAnv(String anv) {
        this.anv = anv;
    }

    public String getTracks() {
        return tracks;
    }

    public void setTracks(String tracks) {
        this.tracks = tracks;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getResource_url() {
        return resource_url;
    }

    public void setResource_url(String resource_url) {
        this.resource_url = resource_url;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}

public class Labels extends RealmObject {

    private String name;
    private String entity_type;
    private String catno;
    private String resource_url;
    private int id;
    private String entity_type_name;

    public Labels() {
    }

    public Labels(String name, String entity_type, String catno, String resource_url, int id, String entity_type_name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.entity_type = entity_type;
        this.catno = catno;
        this.resource_url = resource_url;
        this.id = id;
        this.entity_type_name = entity_type_name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEntity_type() {
        return entity_type;
    }

    public void setEntity_type(String entity_type) {
        this.entity_type = entity_type;
    }

    public String getCatno() {
        return catno;
    }

    public void setCatno(String catno) {
        this.catno = catno;
    }

    public String getResource_url() {
        return resource_url;
    }

    public void setResource_url(String resource_url) {
        this.resource_url = resource_url;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEntity_type_name() {
        return entity_type_name;
    }

    public void setEntity_type_name(String entity_type_name) {
        this.entity_type_name = entity_type_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you rename `setValues`?

Comment: I tried setting up a unit test that simulates your use-case: a class with a non default constructor that uses an instance method to set some fields. I could not reproduce your issue. It would be interesting to see what `setValues()` does.

Comment: @geisshirt I've tried to rename setValues to myParseJson, but the problem is still the same except it references to renamed method. ASAP I'll post my edit with the entire comtents of setValue.

Comment: @Cristian Please take a look at https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/2601

Comment: @geisshirt could you please explain me where I mistake? Thank you!

Comment: Did you solved that? Or is pending to the correct anwswer? I'm with the same error : /

Comment: if you are migrated from jar file to plugin, try to delete realm jar file from lib folder and try again.